# Is $ \tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{x})) $ equal to infinity?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I am solving the equation below:
$$
S = \pi (4 - (p . \tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{p}))^2)
$$
My solution for solving $ \tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{p})) $ is:
$$
\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{p})) =
\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(p)) =
\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) - \tan(\arctan(p))}{ 1 + \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) 
 .\tan(\arctan(p))} =
$$
$$
\frac{∞ - p}{1 + ∞ . p} =
\frac{∞}{∞}
$$
I know it is **wrong**! Please determine my mistake(s) and show me how to solve such equations. thanks!

Comment: The range of the arctangent is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.  On the domain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, the range of the tangent is $(-\infty,\infty)$.  Hence, $\tan(\arctan(x))=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Is your expression $\tan \left( \arctan\left(\frac1p\right)\times \arctan\left(\frac1p\right)\right)?$   Or is your expression $\tan \left( \arctan\left(\frac1p\right)\right)\times \tan \left( \arctan\left(\frac1p\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a trig identity wizard but I can tell you that $\tan(\arctan(x))=x$ as the definition of arctan is the inverse of tan. So you don't need to do all those manipulations to solve for $\tan(\arctan(\frac{1}{p}))$ as that is just $\frac{1}{p}$.  This is consistent with your answer as what you got is undefined and could be any value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it. but why is my method wrong?